# MAVEN - Setting Path in Redhat so the maven commands can be run from anywhere

Tags: maven

I have just installed Maven on Redhat, the apache-maven-3.3.9 is located in /root/, I ran the following command to set the path (JDK java home path already set and when I type $PATH the below path does show, along with when I type mvn --version):

export PATH=/root/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH

The project I want to build with Maven is also in /root/ however, I cannot use the maven commands within the project or anywhere else except for /apache-maven-3.3.9/bin directory.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You say mvn --version works, but not any other maven commands?  What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: mvn --version works but only in apache-maven-3.3.9/bin folder, so no commands are working out of that... If I try to run any maven commands outside the /bin folder I'm simply getting: -bash: ./mvn: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the output of `which mvn` ?

Comment: use `mvn <command>` not `./mvn <command>` The leading `./` will indicate you are inputting a relative path to a file, instead of trying to run a command from $PATH

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your `~/.profile` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/root/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
```

so that when you exit the terminal and start a new terminal instance path is not lost